# iOS - second TableViewController under TabBarController is overlapped by NavigationBar

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have the following storyboard layout:

```
NavigationController
 '-> View Controller
      '-> TabViewController
           '-> TableViewController1
           '-> TableViewController2
```

The problem is when the second tab is selected, the table view (TableViewController2) appears overlapped by the top navigation bar, despite `Under Top Bars` being deselected under `Extend Edges`. The first tab works fine with the same setting.

If I swap the table view controllers between tabs, the problem doesn't swap, it still stays on tab 2.

Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get the question, but is **Adjust Scroll View Insets** checkbox of your view controller selected ?

Comment: Problem still exists even if you deselect it?

Comment: Yes still there. Funny thing is if you segue to another view controller and then go back it is fixed. It is as though the viewcontroller in the second tabview doesnt know that there is a navigation bar.